# Unexpected token import - using react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm getting an error when running my react app: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

*I know that there are a plethora of similar issues on here, but I think mine is a little different*. First of all, here is the repository, since I'm not sure where exactly the error is: [repo](https://github.com/Erody/reddice)

I'm using create-react-app, and in a seperate backend directory I'm using babel (with a .babelrc file containing the preset es2015). The app worked fine until I added another file in a new directory in the backend folder ([/backend/shared/validations/signup.js](https://github.com/Erody/reddice/blob/master/backend/shared/validations/signup.js)).
I was using es6 before that too, and it was working perfectly fine. First I thought it was some problem with windows, but I cloned the repo on my Ubuntu laptop and I'm getting the same error there.

Some things I tried already:

- Move the entire folder from /backend to the root folder
- Move just the file (signup.js) just about everywhere

So no matter where the file is, the error stays the same. If I remove the entire file and all references to it the app works again.

I think this error is pretty weird, considering I'm using es6 everywhere else in the app without trouble. It would be great if anyone could help me with this error.

edit: If you want to test this on your own machine just clone the repo and run `npm start` in the root folder (and also `npm start` in the backend folder, but that isn't required for the app to run, or for the error to show up).

Comment: What file and line is the error occurring?

Comment: Error is occuring in file signup.js on line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what's happening:

Your webpack is set to run babel loader only in the `src` folder (`include` directive).

To change that, one approach is:

**1)** extract webpack configuration with `npm run eject` (don't know if there is another way to override settings in `react-create-app`). From the docs:

> Running npm run eject copies all the configuration files and the
>   transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your
>   project so you have full control over them.

**2)** in `config/paths.js`, add an `appShared` key, like that:

```
module.exports = {
  /* ... */
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  appShared: resolveApp('backend/shared'),
  /* ... */
};
```

**3)** in `config/webpack.config.dev.js`, add the path to the babel loader, like that:

```
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  include: [ paths.appSrc, paths.appShared ],
  loader: 'babel',
  /* ... */
},
```

It works now!